# Show/Hide comments

Tags: comments

I added a snippet for a show/hide function for the comments under a post:

```
function agwp_footerarea()
{
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {
var commentsDiv = $('#comments');
if (commentsDiv.length) {
$(commentsDiv).hide();
$('<button/>').attr('class', 'toggle-comments').attr('href', '#').html('Kommentare anzeigen <span class="icon_comment"></span>').insertBefore(commentsDiv);
$('.toggle-comments').on('click', function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
$(commentsDiv).toggle('slow', function() {
var anchor = $('.toggle-comments');
var anchorText = anchor.html() == 'Kommentare anzeiten <span class="icon_comment"></span>' ? 'Kommentare verbergen <span class="icon_comment"></span>' : 'Kommentare anzeigen <span class="icon_comment"></span>';
$(anchor).html(anchorText);
});
});
}
});
</script>
<?php
}
add_action('wp_footer', 'agwp_footerarea', 100);
```

It works so far.

But I just discovered a small drawback where it doesn't work:
If you click on the number of comments under the post title (like: xxx.de/blog/2023/05/testpost/#comments), then nothing happens.

If I deactivate the snippet (I use "Code Snippets" plugin for it) and click on "1 comment" under the post title, then you actually end up under the post with the comments.

Could you please tell me how I can modify the snippet so that clicking on "x comments" at the top of the meta tags  ends up at the bottom of the comments?

And what else I'm currently thinking of:
wouldn't jQuery be better than Javascript in case someone has disabled JavaScript in their browser?
Thanks!